# Rendering parent element without any changes to child elements

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am stating my current situation and problem into two statements. I am not supposed to upload the code for any reference, so i am illustrating my working model in sentence form.

While working with parent and child elements in react, parent passes some initial values to child as props. Child node can take those values via props and can make further changes. But after the change, parent will never come to know about the updated values of the child. So, the new updated values is confined to children level.

When there is any update and setState() is called on parent, it will try to reconstruct the child with the existing values of child at parent level but not with the updated values at children node.

So, i tried flux event handlers but this is making code more complex with too many calls to and fro between child and parent. I heard of hot-reload, but i am not sure whether it can go with my current situation. I am looking for some best measures to solve my problem.

Comment: ummm, why don't you use redux?

Comment: @illiteratewriter i am already using flux for different action handlers.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted any code, I hope I've understood your problem well.

What comes straight to my mind is using shouldComponentUpdate method in child elements, and checking if any prop that should really re-render child has changed.

Also, in child elements, set initial state after props you receive, but use child elements internal state for rendering.

Hope I've helped you a bit.

Comment: yes, even i tried this and even child renders according to the internal state of the child. But when parent re-renders then it will construct new child with the existing properties at parent level.

Comment: Try connecting child component directly to Redux/Flux, or handle child component updates in parent (container) component, so it controls data that needs to be preserved after parents update.